# Forward only Streaming Java API for Excel

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, apache-poi

I have a web application that supports download of large result sets (400K+ rows) in Excel format. Limitations that I have with Apache POI is that I have to generate entire excel file before I can stream, this is putting lot of stress on application servers.

Is there a way I can stream the excel file partially few rows at a time? This is forward only operation with single worksheet. I will not modify the cells that are already created

I can do this in CSV but formatting is a "must have" requirement here.

Comment: I think Excel is stored as xml so I think the answer is no... CSV works because it's a raw flat file and there's no document start/end.  A solution I have used in the past for problems like this is to offload the generation to servers that just do this, then link them from their, alleviating any processing on the app server which needs to remain responsive.  This should be really easy to do with like Azure or AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the Buffered-streaming [SXSSF Howto](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf), which outlines how you can write a XLSX stream by using mostly the same API as XSSF.

This works by creating a "window" into the worksheet, which moves with the cells that are currently written into. I can attest it works even when creating very large streams.

Note that IIRC this uses temporary storage for the unwritten stream and will only write once the workbook is complete.